# How can I make a ban command for my discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../config.json');
const log = require(`leekslazylogger`);
module.exports = {
  name: 'ban',
  description: 'This is for admins only',
  usage: '',
  aliases: ['Ban'],
  example: '',
  args: false,
  cooldown: config.cooldown,
  guildOnly: true,
  execute(message, args) {
    const client = message.client;
    // command starts here
    message.delete();
```

That's all I have so far. I don't how to make a ban command and I have tried making one but every time I did, I got a lot of errors when the bot starts up. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: 2020-08-06T06:53:06.517090+00:00 app[Worker.1]: [06:53:06 | INFO] Starting up...
2020-08-06T06:53:07.181838+00:00 app[Worker.1]: [06:53:07 | INFO] Initialising bot...
2020-08-06T06:53:07.186131+00:00 app[Worker.1]: /app/commands/Ban.js:18
2020-08-06T06:53:07.186132+00:00 app[Worker.1]: if (msg.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") that happened when I tried about 5 times to make a ban command

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63276796/edit) your question to add the errors

Comment: It seems there's also (probably) missing code in your question (at least there's some `}` missing)

Comment: Alright I will see

Comment: This is what I have made for the ban command ```if (msg.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") {
    if (msg.members.mentions.first()) {
        try {
            msg.members.mentions.first().ban();
        } catch {
            msg.reply("I do not have permissions to ban" + msg.members.mentions.first());
    }else {
        msg.reply("You do not have permissions to ban" + msg.members.mentions.first());
}
}};```

Answer (score 0):

Ill give you some code that u *may* edit to avoid "clone".

You can edit it to do it an embed, if u want
here is it:

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS'))
  return message.channel.send(
    "You can't use that!\nYou need the 'Ban Members' permission"
  );
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
if (!member) {
  message.delete();
  message.channel.send('You need mention someone!');
} else {
  message.delete();
  message.channel.send(
    '<@' + member + '> Has been successfully banned from the guild'
  );
  member.ban(member, reason);
  console.log(`Banned someone on:\n ${message.guild.name} `);
}
```